# Adding a Java project as a Dependency to an Android project with Eclipse

Tags: java, android

Is this possible? I've searched around Stackoverflow for quite a bit already, but I coudln't find an answer.

It compiles without errors, but gives runtime errors and warnings, saying that certain classes were not found.

Comment: Have you tried adding the dependency simply as an external JAR?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, you need to package the other project as a JAR or Android library project, as the Android Eclipse build process will ignore other stuff. You can probably also work out a solution using Gradle, though Gradle for Android is not integrated into Eclipse at this time.

Comment: @Meesh My biggest dislike of this would be that it would slow down bulding and testing, as I'd need to package my Core project as JAR each time I made a change (and I don't know how to automate it)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** 
Yes this is possible. Go to your project properties(right click project -> bottom of the list) and 'Java Build Path', you can add projects and libraries as you wish from this view. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is not adding a Java project. It is adding an Android library project.

Comment: Update added @CommonsWare wrong window but still possible. I Fixed my response.

Comment: Are you sure those get packaged in with the APK? That feels like what the OP tried, and last I knew, the Android packaging tools were unaware of those things you manually added to the build path.

Comment: You are right. It must be a .jar file and added to your build path as a dependency to be included in the build of your .apk file.